# Setting jqgrid variables

Tags: javascript, oop

I have jqgrid that I am using on most of my pages and I want to implement settings for my pages. I have settings defined in my object see below.
I would like to know, if there is a way how to change or override the settings, instead of my mapping every setting.

```
var myGridSettings={
        pager: $("#pager"),
        rowNum: 10,
        width:750,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '',
        loadonce: true,
        caption: gridCaptionName,
        ignoreCase: true,
}
```

Code used from example
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Java Scrpt code ...

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example"
});
```

This is for me to have generic settings for all pages and ensure that all my settings are same.

The only way I know would work as, but this solution has loads of repetition involved on every page

```
 jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'server.php?q=2',  // not using my settings object
        datatype: myGridSettings.datatype,   // using my settings object
        rowNum:myGridSettings.rowNum,
        rowList:myGridSettings.rowList,
        pager: myGridSettings.pager,        
        viewrecords: myGridSettings.viewrecords,      
    });
```

Is there any better way, to set jqgrid object with my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.jqgrid.defaults`. See for example this article : http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options .